# Initialise object in apex with related data

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I require a separate object which contains the related fields of a child object.

Currently I do it like this:

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Id, Account.Name FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];

Account acc = new Account(
    Id        = opp.Account.Id,
    Name      = opp.Account.Name
);
```

When working with a large related object I have to initialise many more fields than this and the script becomes very large and ugly.

What is the quickest way to initialise the related field data into a separate object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the all fields in your SOQL query (mor info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780413/salesforce-soql-query-to-fetch-all-the-fields-on-the-entity)).

But it is not necessary if you want to clone the object:

```salesforce
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Account.Id, Account.Name 
                   FROM Opportunity 
                   LIMIT 1];

Account acc = opp.Account;
```

Example with Custom Object:

```salesforce
Contract__c c = [ Select Account__r.FirstName 
                  From Contract__c 
                  Where Account__r.FirstName != null 
                  Limit 1];

Account a = c.Account__r;
```

Comment: How do you do this with a custom object? If I use opp.Account__c it returns an Id, and if I use opp.Account__r it expects a field. Edit: It seems you can do it using the __r field.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this as answered in a minute but your first statement isnt quite right, you only have to define the fields you want to use in the SOQL query.

Comment: Right, just a tradition from my practice :) Edited now